# Selenium: urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool error

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, pytest

I'm learning QA automatization on Python right now, and I encountered that error trying to start the first and simplest code. I tried several different approaches, but it won't work. I tried to switch off my VPN, I have a good internet connection, I updated all python libraries.

I'm using Python 3.10, pytest 7.1.3, pytest-selenium 4.0.0, selenium 4.4.3, Pycharm 2022.2.2 on Windows 11 Home.

Here is the code I'm trying to launch. The error occurs after google page is open, it won't enter test text into search field and then urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=63146): error occurs.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()


def test_search_example(selenium):
    """ Search some phrase in google and make a screenshot of the page. """

    # Open google search page:
    selenium.get('https://google.com')

    # time.sleep(5)  

    # Find the field for search text input:
    search_input = driver.find_element("name", "q")

    # Enter the text for search:
    search_input.clear()
    search_input.send_keys('first test')

    time.sleep(5) 

    # Click Search:
    search_button = driver.find_element("name", "btnK")
    search_button.click()

    time.sleep(10)  

    # Make the screenshot of browser window:
    selenium.save_screenshot('result.png')

driver.quit()
```

Comment: what line exactly raises the error?

Comment: it seems after this line the error occurs - search_input = driver.find_element("name", "q")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is one issues with you code.

you made the function `test_search_example()` but you never called it.

this should do the trick:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

def test_search_example():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    # Open google search page:
    driver.get('https://google.com')

    time.sleep(5)  

    # Find the field for search text input:
    search_input = driver.find_element("name", "q")

    # Enter the text for search:
    search_input.clear()
    search_input.send_keys('first test')

    time.sleep(5) 

    # Click Search:
    search_button = driver.find_element("name", "btnK")
    search_button.click()

    time.sleep(10)  

    # Make the screenshot of browser window:
    driver.save_screenshot('result.png')

    driver.quit()
    
test_search_example()
```

Comment: Any function starting with test_* would be *collected* anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be mixing the `selenium` from `pytest-selenium` with the `driver` that you spun up independent of that.

Note that you navigated to the URL with the `selenium` var:

```py
selenium.get('https://google.com')
```

But then you performed an action with the `driver` var:

```py
search_input = driver.find_element("name", "q")
search_button = driver.find_element("name", "btnK")
```

So change the `find_element` lines to:

```py
search_input = selenium.find_element("name", "q")
# and this line:
search_button = selenium.find_element("name", "btnK")
```

and then remove all the other lines that contain `driver`:

```py
### Remove these lines:
# from selenium import webdriver
# driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# driver.quit()
```

...and then run with `pytest` so that it uses the `selenium` fixture from `pytest-selenium` for all the selenium actions.

Comment: it worked great too, thanks a bunch! the lesson I'm learning it by was a bit confusing, you explained it much better!